# Retrieve data from Task in windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, deserialization

I'm using this methods to serialize and deserialize ObservableCollections in my app.

```
        public static async void SaveToXmlAsync(string fileName, T classInstanceToSave)
    {
        using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true }))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, classInstanceToSave);
            }
        }
    }

    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> LoadFromXmlAsync(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var files = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFilesAsync(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByName).GetResults();
            var file = files.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == fileName);

            // If the file exists, try and load it it's data.
            if (file != null)
            {
                using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(fileName))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                    T data = (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                    return data;
                }
            }
        }
        // Eat any exceptions unless debugging so that users don't see any errors.
        catch
        {
            if (IsDebugging)
                throw;
        }

        // We couldn't load the data, so just return a default instance of the class.
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

I found this methods in that topic: [click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562268/xml-serialization-in-windows-8/17055641#17055641)

And I don't know how to read saved data. How I can cast Task returned from deserializer method to my collection? I tried that, but it cannot compile:

```
ObservableCollection<Product> collection = Toolkit<ObservableCollection<Product>>.LoadFromXmlAsync("list1.xml");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ObservableCollection<Product> collection = await Toolkit<ObservableCollection<Product>>.LoadFromXmlAsync("list1.xml");
```

Also put **async** keyword to your own method.

Good luck